# Run script into Docker

Tags: linux, bash, docker

I have Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y software-properties-common curl gnupg2 && \
  curl -fsSL https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com/gpg | apt-key add - && \
  apt-add-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com $(lsb_release -cs) main" && \
  apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  vault && \
  setcap cap_ipc_lock= /usr/bin/vault

COPY run.sh ./

CMD ./run.sh
```

And my run.sh file

```
#!/bin/bash

VAULT_RETRIES=5
echo "Vault is starting..."
until vault status > /dev/null 2>&1 || [ "$VAULT_RETRIES" -eq 0 ]; do
        echo "Waiting for vault to start...: $((VAULT_RETRIES--))"
        sleep 1
done

echo "Authenticating to vault..."
vault login token=vault-plaintext-root-token

echo "Initializing vault..."
vault secrets enable -version=2 -path=my.secrets kv

echo "Adding entries..."
vault kv put my.secrets/dev username=test_user
vault kv put my.secrets/dev password=test_password

echo "Complete..."
```

When i run docker i have problem -

> /bin/sh: 1: ./run.sh: not found

If i replace

> CMD ./run.sh

on

> RUN chmod +x run.sh

container runs without issues, but script is not worked, because i don't see in terminal echo commands

Comment: Replacing `CMD` with `RUN` doesn't make any sense -- those two commands do very different things. `CMD` means "run this command when the container starts", while `RUN` means "run this command now while building the image".

Comment: What is the `WORKDIR`? Did you try giving the absolute path to `run.sh` in CMD?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was in `#!/bin/bash`. I rewrote this on `#!/bin bash` and my script is finding. But i had second problem it's -  `exec user process caused "permission denied"`. This problem was resolved- i added `RUN chmod +rx run.sh` command in Dockerfile and script encoding should be utf-8 + BOM (for Windows).